# В каком порядке нужно создавать таблицу разделов и контейнер luks?

Tags: linux, шифрование

Я хочу полностью зашифровать свой USB-накопитель с помощью luks. В каком порядке нужно создавать таблицу разделов и контейнер luks? Создать таблицу разделов, а затем контейнер luks, или контейнер с таблицей разделов внутри?

Какой из способов правильный и почему?

Answer (score 2):

В любом случае, сначала создаётся таблица разделов. Случай "контейнер с таблицей разделов внутри", возможно, подразумевал настройку LVM внутри созданного зашифрованного раздела, что в простом варианте необязательно.

Порядок действий можно подсмотреть [тут](https://losst.ru/shifrovanie-diskov-v-linux).